# How can I set a PHP variable equal to a JQuery variable and then insert it into a MySQL database?

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql

I am fairly new to coding and developing websites and for my first project I decided to make a clicker website using PHP, JQuery and MySQL. 
However, I have run into a issue.  By using the click() function on the image I am easily able to increment the clout variable by 1, and the text on the button changes, however when I attempt to click on the button to send the variable over to my php file, nothing happens.  Any help?  I have left the needed code down below.

click.php:

```
<div class="container-main">
    <img src="img/inCloutWeTrust.JPG" id="cloutImg" onclick="addClout()" />
</div>
<input type="submit" id="submitB" value="No Clout Available To Claim!" id="text" class="cloutButton">
</div>
<script>
    var clout = 0;
    $("#cloutImg").click(function() {
        clout += 1;
        if (clout == 1) {
            $("#submitB").val('Claim 1 Clout Token');
        } else if (clout > 1) {
            $("#submitB").val('Claim ' + clout + ' Clout Tokens');
        }
    });

    $("#submitB").click(function() {
        $.post("addclout.php", {variable: clout});
    });
</script>
```

addclout.php

```
<?php
    require 'core.inc.php';
    require 'connect.inc.php';
    $clout = $_POST['variable'];
    $query = "UPDATE `users` SET `clout`=`clout` +".$clout." WHERE `id`='" + $_SESSION['user_id'] + "'";
    if (mysql_query($query)) {
        header('Location: index.php');
    }
?>
```

I am also certain that the MySql query is correct because I manually put it in (minus the variables) on PHPMyAdmin.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Because at least concatenation in php is done with `.` and not with `+`

Comment: Please also note that the `mysql_` constructor is [**deprecated as of PHP 5.5**](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation), and is outright [**removed in PHP 7**](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/remove_deprecated_functionality_in_php7#extmysql). Please consider switching to either [**MySQLi**](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [**PDO**](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php), ensuring that you also use [**parameterised queries**](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) to prevent [**SQL injection**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) :)

Comment: In PHP, you concatenate using a `.`. You'll be best mates with [little bobby drop tables](https://xkcd.com/327/) in no time if you don't santize those inputs too.

Comment: Along with @ObsidianAge's comment - If you can't decide which to use, [this article will help to choose your best option](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton -- A great link that I wasn't aware of. Thanks, will add this to my list :) However, yes, the main problem appears to be use of a `+` instead of a `.` in `$query`.

Comment: @ObsidianAge No problem glad I could give you some more resources ^.^

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Change "+" to "." to concatenate and add connection to mysql_query function.

```
<?php
    require 'core.inc.php';
    require 'connect.inc.php';
    // ALWAYS parse data from client to prevent SQL Inyection
    $clout = intval( $_POST['variable'] );
    // Change "+" to "." to concatenate
    $query = "UPDATE `users` SET `clout` = `clout` + ".$clout." WHERE `id` = '".$_SESSION['user_id']."'";
    // Add connection and you should use "mysqli" 
    if ( mysql_query( $query, $conn ) )
    {
        header('Location: index.php');
    }
?>
```